# Prolog - how to generate list of specific length?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm doing this exercise for which I have to write a predicate `randomnames/1` for generating a random list of three names (no duplicates allowed). I have a database with 10 names in it already and they all correspond to a number, for example: `name(1, Mary).`
I wrote a predicate for generating one random name:

```
randomname(Name) :- 
   random(0, 11, N),    % generate random integer between 1 and 10.
   name(N, Name).
```

My question would be: How do I get this in a list? And a list of exactly three elements at that?
I don't want to use too many built-ins. `length/2` would be alright though. I think I might need it :)

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I figured I would first try to generate a list of three random numbers (the names can come later). I wrote this horribly wrong little thing:

```
numberlist([N|T]) :-
   random(0, 11, N),
   length([N|T], 3),
   numberlist(T).
```

I know how to do this with a /2 predicate; when the user can just enter in the query that they want a list with three elements (`numberlist(3,X).`for example). But I'm can't seem to figure out how to write down in code that I always want a list of three numbers. 
I was also thinking of using `findall` for generating my list, but again I don't know how to limit the length of the list to three random elements.

Comment: How many is too many built-ins?

Comment: Well I guess I can use `random` and `length` and the basic `is` and such, but because it's an exercise you're not supposed to use built-ins except when they're absolutely necessary. If you have a way with builtins though, I would love to see it!

Comment: Oh and `findall` and `bagof` are possible too!

Answer (score 2):

When describing *lists* in Prolog, it is often useful to first describe how a *single element* looks like.

For example, in your case, it seems you already have a predicate like `random_name/1`, and it describes a single element of the list you want to describe.

So, to describe a list consisting of *three* such elements, what about:

```
random_names([A,B,C]) :-
        random_name(A),
        random_name(B),
        random_name(C).
```

This describes a list with three elements, and `random_name/1` holds for each of these elements.

Comment: That is actually a very good solution! I have been thinking way too complex. The only problem is that there can't be duplicates in the list and I'm not sure how to program that using your approach. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think this should be best discussed in a separate question.